# Function name must be a string error

Tags: php

Im getting this error

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/an011500/www_root/nastavenia.php on line 32

Can you help me fix this?

EDIT:
Whole code

php_functions.php file

```
 <?php


  function check_username($user_name)
    {
    require('PDO_DB_connect.php');
    $sql_query1= "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username=:username";
    $query1 = dbConnect()->prepare($sql_query1);
    $query1->bindParam(':username', $user_name);
    $query1->execute();
    if($query1->rowCount() == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

nastavenia.php file

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $session_set = true; 
}
elseif(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("location: index.php");
    $session_not_set = true;
}

require('PDO_DB_connect.php');
require('php_functions.php');

$user_name = osetri_string($_POST['username']);
$email = osetri_string($_POST['email']);
$password = osetri_string($_POST['password']);
$confirm_password = osetri_string($_POST['password1']);
$actual_password = osetri_string($_POST['actual_password']);


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['actual_password']))
    {
        if(check_username($user_name) === true)
        {
           if(isset($_POST['username_radio_button']))
            {
            $prepared_username_sql_query = "UPDATE user SET username=:username WHERE username=:actual_username AND password=:actual_password";
            $username_sql_query($prepared_username_sql_query);
            $username_sql_query->bindParam('username' ,$user_name);
            $username_sql_query->bindParam('actual_username' ,$_SESSION['username']);
            $username_sql_query->bindParam('actual_password' ,$actual_password );
            if($username_sql_query->execute())
               {
                $user_info = "not a fail?";
               }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $username_error = "fail";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

My post is mostly code? Fine.
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: What is line 32?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with this code

Comment: Can you please comment where is your line 32?

Comment: Is `do stuff` supposed to be commented?

Comment: didn't you post something similar already http://stackoverflow.com/q/29580405/ but now it's in a function; *weirdlysome*.

Comment: oh never mind, you're ignoring everything here anyway. check your connection, who f'knows.

Comment: Fred -ii-My connection is fine,

Comment: You are opening <?php when you don't need to.

Comment: $username_sql_query($prepared_username_sql_query); <-- what is $username_sql_query

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to call the function name stored in `$username_sql_query` here...

```
$username_sql_query($prepared_username_sql_query);
```

But on the very next line, you refer to that same variable as an object...

```
$username_sql_query->bindParam('username' ,$user_name);
```

If `$username_sql_query` is an object, then that first line should probably also be a method call.

I would also give some meta-advice here - you posted a lot of code when PHP was telling you exactly which line was at fault. If you studied that one line, and perhaps dumped the variables to see if they contained what you expected, you would have solved this in less time than it's taken me to write this paragraph :)

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds!

Comment: Is it possible to give  you reputation? for help?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow - simply upvote answers which helped you, and mark this as the accepted answer if it helped you find what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks my my comment helped answer your question... This was what fixed the problem for people wondering later on. It'd be appreciated if you accepted this as the answer.

```
$username_sql_query =dbConnect()->prepare("UPDATE user SET username=:username WHERE username=:actual_username AND password=:actual_password");
$username_sql_query->bindParam(':username' ,$user_name);
$username_sql_query->bindParam(':actual_username' ,$_SESSION['username']);
$username_sql_query->bindParam(':actual_password' ,$actual_password );
```

When binding the parameter OP was using 'username' instead of ':username' along with 'actual_username' and 'actual_password' instead of having the colon preceding them.

Comment: ah no, its the php_functions.php file which is required later. I must edit my post

Comment: Line 32 looks to be this: `$username_sql_query->bindParam('username' ,$user_name);`

Try changing it to this: `$username_sql_query->bindParam(":username" ,$user_name);`

Not the colon which matches with your query parameters. If that works you'll likely get an error on line 33 and 34 because you are omitting the colon for that as well. Let me know if this fixes it and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works, I had many errors in code like not including the : after username in bindParam

So.. now my code looks like this and it works...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['actual_password']))
    {
        if(check_username($user_name) === true)
        {
           if(isset($_POST['username_radio_button']))
            {
            $username_sql_query =dbConnect()->prepare("UPDATE user SET username=:username WHERE username=:actual_username AND password=:actual_password");
            $username_sql_query->bindParam(':username' ,$user_name);
            $username_sql_query->bindParam(':actual_username' ,$_SESSION['username']);
            $username_sql_query->bindParam(':actual_password' ,$actual_password );
            if($username_sql_query->execute())
               {
                $user_info = "not a fail?";
               }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $username_error = "fail";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped answer the question, please accept it as the answer.